# My problem that I can access Pinia state anywhere except inside Axios body. Why?

Tags: axios, quasar-framework, pinia

I'm using Pinia, Axios, Quasar
everything work except one thing.

this is my code:

```
    state: () => ({
    userName: "",
    userEmail: "",
    token: "",
  
  }),
actions: {
    async login(username, password) {
      //console.log(`Bearer ${this.token}`);
      var user = {
        username: username.value,
        password: password.value,
      };
      var t = "";
      await axios
        .post("https://localhost:7214/Auth/login/", user)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(`${token}`);  // here tell me token is not defined
          this.token = response;  // here tell me token is not defined
          t = response.data;
         
        
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          // handle error
          console.log(error);
        })
        .finally(function () {
          // always executed
        });
      this.token= t;  // here token is work without error
    },
```

My problem that i can access token state anywhere except inside axios body. Why?

Comment: I don't understand why someone will mark this question as un-clear. or at least ask for details or just ignore it